# Как вставить символ двойных кавычек в строку?

Tags: java, android, строки

Пример:

```
String str1 = "Строка со "словом" в кавычках";
```

Как корректно вставить символ кавычек (")?

Comment: str1 = 'Строка со "словом" в кавычках';

Comment: @alexkad, это не JavaScript, а Java. тут такое не работает.

Comment: @kaaa, это называется экранирование символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final char dm = (char) 34;
final String string = "STRING: " + dm + " string " + dm;
System.out.println(string);
```

Вывод:

> STRING: " string "

Comment: Вообще не понял, а за что заминусовали? У меня всё отработало прекрасно.

Answer (score 33):

Самый стандартный способ, применяемый во многих языка, в том числе и в *Java* - экранирование с помощью символа `\`:

```
String myString = "Строка со \"словом\" в кавычках";
```

Comment: Это еще называется [escape символ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Comment: Благодарю, это работает, но задача усложнилась.Перед кавычками еще надо поставить слеш +"<IMG SRC=\"file://"+

Comment: решается аналогично

Comment: Да, действительно

Comment: в конце строки кавычки лишние

Comment: Самый стандартный способ, применяемый во многих языка, в том числе и в Java - экранирование с помощью символа \: СПАСИБО!!! я новичок, Ваш совет мне очень помог.

Answer (score 11):

```
String str1 = "Строка со \"словом\" в кавычках";
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, есть, добавляешь перед каждым символом который нужно экранировать `\`.
Например, для вывода на экран `"C: \\\folder\\\folder1\"` нужно добавить по "экрану" перед КАЖДЫМ символом вот так:

```
System.out.println("\"C: \\\\\\\folder\\\\\\\folder1\\\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String x = "\\";
    String y = "\"";
    System.out.println("It's Windows path: " + y + "C:" + x + "Program Files" + x + "Java" + x + "jdk1.7.0" + x + "bin" + y);
    System.out.println("It's Java string: " + x + y + "C:" + x + x + "Program Files" + x + x + "Java" + x + x + "jdk1.7.0" + x + x + "bin" + x + y);
```

Comment: Решение задачи с JavaRush, верно? А есть "нормальный" способ экранировать кавычки?

Comment: @Dunaevsky Maxim, А символом для экранирования экранировать не нормально? :)